# How can I display Laravel images on a live server?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I developed a laravel app which is working perfectly on my local machine together with the images. On deployment to live server, the images are no longer visible. I am using shared hosting and my folder structure is like this: **public_html** containing the public files like upload and **main** containing the remaining files which should not be visible to the user. Here is my controller `public function

```
PortfolioAdd(){
        return view('frontendbackend.portfoliosection.addportfolio');
    }

    public function PortfolioStore(Request $request){

            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required:portfolio_sections,title',
                'description' => 'required:portfolio_sections,description',
            
            
        ]);

        $data = new PorfolioSection();
        $data->title = $request->title;
        $data->description = $request->description;

        if ($request->file('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $filename = date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path('upload/portfolio_images'),$filename);
            $data['image'] = $filename;
        }
     
        $data->save();
```

`and here is my view

```
                  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style = "color:white">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
            <th width="5%" style = "color:white">SL</th>
            <th style = "color:white">Title</th>
            <th style = "color:white">Description</th>
            <th style = "color:white">Image</th>
            <th style = "color:white">Action</th>    
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    @foreach($allData as $key => $portfolio )
        <tr>
            <td style = "color:white"> {{ $key+1 }} </td>
            <td> {{ $portfolio->title }} </td>
            <td> {{ $portfolio->description }} </td>
            <td> 
                
                <img src="{{ (!empty($portfolio->image))? url('upload/portfolio_images/'.$portfolio->image):url('upload/no_image.jpg') }}" style="width: 60px; width: 60px;"> 
                           </td>    

            
            <td>
            <a href="{{route('view.portfolio.edit', $portfolio->id)}}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
            <a href="{{route('view.portfolio.delete', $portfolio->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                         
                    </tfoot>
                  </table>
```

Comment: Did you link the storage with `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: Nope. Please how can I do that. Thank you for your response

Comment: You are storing the images in public_html? Normally you store the files in the storage folder...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to create a folder inside your public folder e.g portfolio_images.

```php
if ($request->has('photo')) {
    $photoName= time() . 'photo' . $request->photo->extension();
    $request->photo->move(public_path('portfolio_images'), $photoName);
}
```

This will save it in **public/portfolio_images**.

Then in your view

```html
 <img id="previewImg" src="{{ asset("portfolio_images/$portfolio->image") }}" alt="Preview your image" height="150">
```

This should solve it!

Answer (score 0):

First check whether ($portfolio->image) is showing any value by passing it directly in the  tag i.e

{{ $portfolio->image}}

if it returns values, check whether the value exists in your folder.
If it exists ch then check your image src.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually in my PUBLIC_HTML i created a folder called upload then in upload I have other folders where the images should be uploaded to for portfolio I have PORTFOLIO_IMAGES in the PUBLIC_HTML. However whenever I upload an image it altomatically creates a new folder in MAIN and calls it PORTFOLIO_IMAGES and the puts the image there instead of uploading it to PUBLIC_HTML under the UPLOADS folder I created. So that is preventing the image from displaying on the html. Please is there a way around this? Thank you once more for your patience and time

Comment: the easiest way to do it is to create a folder inside your public folder e.g portfolio_images.

Comment: the easiest way to do it is to create a folder inside your public folder e.g portfolio_images. then 

            if ($request->has('photo')) {
                $photoName= time() . 'photo' . $request->receipt->extension();
                $request->photo->move(public_path('portfolio_images'), $photoName);
            }
This will save it in public>portfolio_images. Then in your view
write
 <img id="previewImg" src="{{ asset("portfolio_images/$$portfolio->image") }}"
                                    alt="Preview your image" height="150">
This should solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following(have not tested)

change this: `$file->move(public_path('upload/portfolio_images'),$filename);`

to: `$file->move(public_path() . 'upload/portfolio_images',$filename);`

Comment: Thank you for your help. But that just created another folder in the MAIN DIRECTORY called publicupload and dumped the picture there. I want the picture to be in the public_html folder so that i can display it to the browser. Or is there a way to display it to the browser directly from the MAIN folder sir. I would truely appreciate if this can be resolved. I am grateful to all who have made an attempt in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must  create a symbolink link for that.
The default folder for uploading files is the storage folder.
By running php artisan storage:link, the application will generate a symbolic link that files will be accebile from the public area.
Google symbolic link. You will find the answer.